# Scope in your query does not exist

Tags: search, object-model, search-scope

I'm developing a web part (in VS 2010 for SharePoint 2010) to seach all content in a Publishing Site Collection. I have the following code (just testing before I change the scope and the select fields) :

```
FullTextSqlQuery q = new FullTextSqlQuery(SPContext.Current.Site);

q.QueryText = "SELECT ContentType FROM SCOPE() WHERE \"scope\"='All Sites'";

q.ResultTypes = ResultTypes.RelevantResults;

ResultTableCollection qr = q.Execute();
```

When (in debug) it gets to the last line I get the following error :

"ScopeNotFoundException was handled by user code"

"Scope in your query does not exist"

I have also tried this on a team site and get the same error. If I remove the scope condition ("SELECT ContentType FROM SCOPE()") I get results returned. Obviously the 'All Sites' scope is shared (I tried this after a custom scope didn't work). The search on the publishing site works as normal.

I have also made sure that my scopes are shared (tried with some custom scopes to no avail).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While not a direct answer, this [codeplex tool](http://sharepointsearchserv.codeplex.com/) may help with building the correct syntax for the query.

Answer (score 1):

Two assemblies with same class:
Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Query.FullTextSqlQuery
Use this one instead: Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.FullTextSqlQuery

Comment: While this may answer the question it doesn't explain why. Please consider revising your question to include more detail.